# Separating android app function's and design

Tags: java, android

i am writing new android app. It's my first app on android.

I want to separate functions of app (retrieving data from sqlite, requesting and handling data from   web service) etc... and design (layouts, interaction between activities, animation).

So maybe someone work like this and could give me some idea's how this should work. Maybe there are some examples.

I think of creating one big class which would main function class and there would be all methods these methods would call other classes for current of need.

In java i would do this:

```
MainClass main = new MainClass();

main.getUsersName();
....
```

but programming with android i don't no how to do this.

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same like as java Dont' worry....

Sqlite objSqlite= new Sqlite ();
objSqlite.getUsersName();

Webparser objParser = new Webparser ();

objParser.getData();

You can pass parameters in method and Constructor same as java and also return type in method.....

And in layout see this ..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html

Animation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html